# audio dynamic range compression in php

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, compression

Is this possible to dynamic audio range compression in PHP. There is a lot of confusion between compression of audio, what I mean of audio compression here is described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) article.

Some posts I saw here about the audio compression which only converts the audio format from wav to mp3 or other formats using FFmpeg, but what I want here is to change some audio settings like threshold, compression ratio, attack time, release time which is basic settings that can be used in audio compression.

Is there any way I can do this in server-side using PHP?

Comment: IMHO, PHP is the wrong tool here. I'm sure you _could_ do it in PHP, but you would probably need to write _a lot_ of very complex and advanced code for it. It would probably also be many many times slower than something built in c++ or similar. If you need to do it on a web site, I would look for some software that does this and has a CLI interface that you can call from PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah I understand what you are saying, actually I need to build a recording tool in my website that can record audio, but that audio is completely uncompressed and on runtime i don't think browser have ability to compress the audio. So that's why i need to do this on server side. Thank for you efforts any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need it in real-time and it’s a recording tool, you’ll want to look at JavaScript WebAudio

Comment: @fdcpp i have searched about it already but didn't found any proper solution that's why i want it to do this on server side.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode

Comment: @fdcpp this is also a very helpful link, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solutions,

Solution 1. Using `dynaudnorm` filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter:a "dynaudnorm" out.wav
```

Solution 2. `compand` filter

`ffmpeg -i in.mp3  -filter_complex \ "compand=attacks=0:points=-30/-900|-20/-20|0/0|20/20" \ out.wav`

Solution 1 works for me.
More Reference: [article1](https://medium.com/@jud.dagnall/dynamic-range-compression-for-audio-with-ffmpeg-and-compand-621fe2b1a892) [article2](https://superuser.com/questions/1303036/adjusting-audio-with-varying-loudness-recorded-talks-with-ffmpeg)